# How to change gridview cell background image according to data from LINQ to entities?

Tags: asp.net

I am new to LINQ and ADO.net EF. I have a column called 'Change' in my ITM table which stores values of type double. I want to change the background image of the GridView cell according to the value in the 'Change' column retrieved using LINQ to Entites. Here's my code.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    using (mydbEntities myEntities = new mydbEntities())
    {
        foreach (var price in myEntities.ITMs)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if (price.Change == 0)
                    e.Row.Cells[5].Attributes.Add("Style", "background: url(../Images/nc.png) no-repeat 5px center;");
                else if (price.Change > 0)
                    e.Row.Cells[5].Attributes.Add("Style", "background: url(../Images/inc.png) no-repeat 5px center;");
                else if (price.Change < 0)
                    e.Row.Cells[5].Attributes.Add("Style", "background: url(../Images/dec.png) no-repeat 5px center;");
            }

        }       

    }
}
```

When this code is run I get the same background image in every cell of the Gridview column regardless of the value. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Row_DataBound is fired once per row and you are doing a foreach inside it. What this means is that you are iterating ≈ n<sup>2</sup> times over a grid with n rows.

Your code will only have effect on the last row of the grid since that will be the last time that your if `(if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow))` will evaluate to true. Your code is iterating unnecessarily and won't work.

What you can do instead is something like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
      double price = double.Parse(rowView["price"].ToString());
      if(price==0.0)
      {
          e.Row.Cells[5].Attributes.Add("Style", "background: url(../Images/nc.png) no-repeat 5px center;");
      }
      else if(price > 0.0 )
      {
          //....
      }
      //etc

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have tried this approach but I want to change the background image using value from the database.

Comment: @advrjn: check my answer again. I've updated it so that it uses the value from the database, as you want it. That should definitely work

Comment: Hi, I tried your updated code. It throws an invalid cast exception at `DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;`.

Comment: Check what's the type returned by e.Row.DataItem and go from there

Answer (score 0):

You can access your data through `e.Item.DataItem` property inside `**ItemDataBound**` event. You will need to cast this to the correct type, to access `price.Change` values.

```
if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
{
    var data = e.Item.DataItem;
    // ....
    if (data.price.Change = 0)...
}
```

This event is fired for each row, corresponding to your data source.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. There were build errors when I used your code. It says you can't use e.Item with GridViewRowEventArgs.

Comment: Use ItemDataBound event instead.